# Can Emeditor Perform a search and replace only to the Selected Column

Tags: csv, emeditor

I was using Emeditor and trying to search and replace within a csv file but I was unable to figure out if there is a way to make the search and replace just work on a particular column.  So if I wanted column 3 to be edited with a search for x and replace with y, it would not change x to y anywhere but that column.

I like how easy it is to make edits.

It is such a great program in any case, thanks to Emeditor.  I can search and replace inside filtered results which I really liked after I figured it out.

Comment: If you replace while filtered, the changes should apply only to filtered lines. If not, please clarify your question with a simplified reproducible sample.

Comment: Indeed it is true.  Amazing Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Emeditor does that.  There is a button that toggles on and off "within selection only" and it works.  Be careful that the selection of the column is also in place right before "change all"